# CSS box Inverse Circle and SlideShow

Tags: css

I'm trying to do with CSS something like the image:
http://i331.photobucket.com/albums/l441/designdigitall/h.png

I need to get a slideshow below, but it only works with background in image, slideshow or iframe to put always in the wrong place and over.

http://i331.photobucket.com/albums/l441/designdigitall/ask03.jpg

Please help me.

Below the code

Thank you

```
<style type="text/css">
    body {
    margin: 0;
    }
    #slidetudo {
    width: 1002px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }


    .inversePair22 {
        border: 0px solid black;
        display: inline-block;    
        position: relative;    
        height: 248px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 100px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        z-index: 5;
    }
    .inversePair {
        border: 0px solid black;
        display: inline-block;    
        position: relative;    
        height: 248px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 100px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        background: #CC0003; /* para browsers sem suporte a CSS 3 */

        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#CC0003', endColorstr='#26070D'); /* IE */

        -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#CC0003', endColorstr='#26070D')"; /* IE8 */

        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#CC0003), to(#26070D)); /* webkit browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #CC0003,  #26070D); /* Firefox 3.6+ */

    }

    #a {
        width: 547px;
        border-radius: 200px;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    #a:before {
        content:' ';
        left: 0px;
        top: 0px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 620px; /* 5px gap */
        height: 248px;
        border-top-right-radius: 200px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 200px;
        background-color: white;
        background-image:url(carros/fotos2/g201403141317532273cdddc2e.jpg);
    } 

    #b {
        width: 510px;
        z-index: 0;
        padding-left: 0px;
        margin-left: -60px;
        overflow: hidden; 

        }

    #b:before {
        left: -60px;
        top: -0px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 3;
        width: 114px; /* 5px gap, 1px border */
        height: 114px;
        border-radius: 57px;
    } 

    #imagemzin img {
        width: 600px;
        height: 248px;
        z-index: 2;
        position: absolute;
    } 

    </style>


<div id="slidetudo">
    <div id="a" class="inversePair22">

        <div id="imagemzin">
            <!----slide-or-iframeCodeHere--but-not-work------>
            <img src="http://i331.photobucket.com/albums/l441/designdigitall/slideteste.jpg" border="0" />
        </div>

</div>

<div id="b" class="inversePair">test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will be easier for you to give your images a border radius (or a border radius for the slideshow container div) than to make a transparent image to show the slideshow through. http://jsfiddle.net/B9sLT/3/

```
    border-top-left-radius: 40px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 40px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 40px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
-moz-border-radius-bottom-left: 40px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
```

*updated fiddle to show you how it looks on the gradient background. the example image that you have linked is two layered images, which is easier for most people to create bc it does not use as much css.